# Finding "position" in DOM of clicked link

Tags: jquery

I have a page with a number of links with a class called "myLinkClass". These links can reside in one of two DOM structures:

```
<div class="divClassA">
    <a class="myLinkClass" ...
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="divClassB">
    <a class="myLinkClass" ...
</div>
```

I hook up the click event of the links with the class to an event handler with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.myLinkClass').bind('click', function (event) {
        //...
    });
});
```

**How can I find out if the clicked link is inside a divClassA or a divClassB?**

Note that although the links are immeditate childrens to the divs in the examples above, that might not be the case. Also, there might be an arbitrary number of both divClassA and divClassB (not just one of each).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check to see if the clicked element has an [ancestor](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) with `divClassA`. If not, you should be able to assume it's in `divClassB`:

```
$('.myLinkClass').bind('click', function (event) {
    if($(this).closest(".divClassA").length) {
        //Inside divClassA
    }
    else {
        //Not inside divClassA!
    }
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/gjaJ6/) of the above.

Answer (score 1):

could be

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.myLinkClass').bind('click', function (event) {
        if($(this).parents('.divClassB').length) {
           //parent has divClassB
        }
    });
});
```

however, if you're trying to create different events for different "divClasses", something like this might be more adequate:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.divClassA .myLinkClass').bind('click', function (event) {
        //in divClassA
    });
    $('.divClassB .myLinkClass').bind('click', function (event) {
        //in divClassB
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm afraid that your first example won't work since the link is not necessary an immediate child of the div. The second example would surely work though, but I'd prefer to have only one event handler.

Comment: @haagel, ".parents()" goes up the whole DOM tree.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this :

```
var parent = $(this).parent;
var parentName = parent.attr('class');
```

Comment: I'm afraid that won't work since the link is not necessary an immediate child of the div.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.myLinkClass').bind('click', function (event) {
    if $(this).parent('div.divClassB') {
       ... it's in a classB ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="divClassB">
    <a class="myLinkClass">click1</a>
</div>
<div class="divClassA">
    <a class="myLinkClass">click2</a>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.myLinkClass').bind('click', function (event) {
    alert($(this).parent().attr('class')); 
});
```

In this code alert will show the class name of parent div. If you want to use this name in condition then try with the following (if you have more than 2 `<a>` tag):

```
$('.myLinkClass').bind('click', function (event) {
    switch($(this).parent().attr('class'))
    {
         case 'divClassB':
                    //do your stuff
                    break;
         case 'divClassA':
                    //do your stuff
                    break;
    } 
});
```

Comment: I'm afraid that won't work since the link is not necessary an immediate child of the div.